# Customizing Navigation Buttons' Bar in MS Access Form

Tags: database, ms-access, customization, vba, ms-access-2010

I am creating a form in MS Access. My form appears to the user in form of a modal pop-up box. At the bottom of the form we get Navigation Buttons, New Entry (which I have disabled), Filter and Search Options.

I want to customize this Navigation Button Bar. For example, I do not want 'Record' word to appear at the left most position in this bar.

[image: Navigation Bar]

I have been searching ways to do the same. I am not sure if the same can be achieved, but still hopeful.

Thanks in anticipation.

Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the *Record* into something else, but not customize the other bits of the navigation bar as far as I know.

[image: Form properties]

Will show as:

[image: Customised navigation bar]

If you want to go further than that, you may be able to intercept windows messages and change the wording on the fly, but that would complex and certainly a lot of work for not much.

On the other hand you could simply not show the navigation bar and create your own navigation using buttons and a bit of VBA instead.

Comment: This is only valid for later versions of MS Access (2007-) as I mention in my earlier post.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Navigation Buttons in form properties, which means the bar does not appear and in Access 2007 and 2010, you can set the Navigation Caption, which means you can have something instead of "Record", but you cannot customize the bar itself.

If you must have custom navigation, disable the bar and add your own navigation options.